# How to make a reader like the kindle app?

Tags: ios, core-text

I'd like to make a reader that behaves like Amazon's Kindle app. Specifically, I want to present a bunch of justified text in paragraphs, one column per page, and have it scroll between pages like the Kindle app does.

Let's assume I have the text in a simple format, like a text file per chapter, or even a string hard-coded in memory per chapter.

They're obviously using Core Text. Are they using a paged scroll view? Would that run in to memory problems for large books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making something completely custom. It consists of 3 views, a `left` `main` and `right` view.

The view controller renders the text on the `main` view using Core Text, and calculates the size of the text frames (and therefore the number of pages) for each page in the current chapter.

If the user taps or drags right or left, the view controller will render one of the side views and let you drag it on. When you finish dragging or complete the tap action, it animates the pages into place, then swaps the main view with the one you dragged on.

The advantage to this method over using a `UICollectionView` is that it's very expensive to calculate the exact contents that should be displayed on a given page in a deterministic way, as a table/collection view would require. This way allows me to render the text of any chapter, and go back or forward lazily without laying out the whole book at once.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that they are using a UITextView to display a large amount of text, this kind of view allows you to add margin, padding, text and for iOS 6 you could use something like NSParagraphStyle to give styling to the text, the easy approach would be to create a really long text in different UITextViews within a UIScrollView and that would give you a nice result however if memory is a concern and the iOS version is not a problem I'd recommend using UICollectionViews, you can make each page a "cell" and then write some custom layout so when the user is scrolling the book you can actually just instanciate the page the user is using at a certain moment

The cool thing about NSCollectionView is that it behaves exactly like a UITableView so it's very memory efficient, something that is not on the screen is not displayed, and if it's going to be displayed then it's loaded.

hope this can give you some insight on the matter.